# Showing $\mathrm{int}(A-B)=\mathrm{int}(A)- \bar{B}$

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that this is true: $\mathrm{int}(A-B)=\mathrm{int}(A)- \bar{B}$.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I don't see where this goes, so started to write simple inclusions.
We know that $int(A) \subset int(A-B)$.

Comment: Is $A-B = A \cap B^c$?

Comment: I think @FlyingHouse meant to write $A\backslash B.$

Comment: @FlyingHouse Don't you mean $int(A-B) \subseteq int(A)$?

Answer (score 2):

int($A -B$) = int($A \cap B^c$) = (int $A$) $\cap$ (int $B^c$) 
= (int $A$) $\cap(\bar B)^c$ = (int $A$) $-\bar B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Observe that $\mathsf{int}(A)-\overline B$ is an *open* subset of $A-B$.

Conversely:

- $A-B\subseteq A\implies\mathsf{int}(A-B)\subseteq\mathsf{int}(A)$
- $A-B\subseteq B^{\complement}\implies\mathsf{int}(A-B)\subseteq\mathsf{int}(B^{\complement})=\cdots$

Comment: @SimonFraser Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with your comment.

Comment: I meant to say, how do you know that $\mathrm{int}(A)-\overline{B}$ is an *open* subset of $A-B$? Is it from some basic identity?

Comment: @SimonFraser I am saying that $\mathsf{int}(A)-\overline B$ is open (not $\mathsf{int}(A)-B$ ). This because it is the intersection of open sets  $\mathsf{int}A$ and $\overline{B}^{\complement}$.

Comment: Do you agree that $\mathsf{int}(A)-\overline B$ is open? If so then what *is* your question?

Comment: yes it is open. my question is, why does $\mathrm{int}(B^C)=\overline{B}^C$? I tried looking up basic properties of interior, but I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: @SimonFraser In short: $\mathsf{int}(B^{\complement})$ is the largest open set that is contained in $B^{\complement}$ so is the complement of smallest closed set that contains $B$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not discussing trivial cases.If $(A - B)^0$ is non empty,let $x \in (A-B)^0$.then there exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that $N(x,\epsilon) \subset A-B\subset A$,so $x\in A^0$,Now if $x\in \bar B$,then every nbd of $x$ should contain some element of $B$.
But $N(x,\epsilon)\subset B^c$,so $N(x,\epsilon)\cap B=\phi$,which is a contradiction.So $x \notin \bar B$.Thus $x\in A^0-\bar B$.Thus $(A-B)^0 \subset A^0-\bar B$.Conversely let $x\in A^0-\bar B$.then there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that $N(x,\epsilon)\subset A$ but $N(x,\epsilon)\cap B=\phi$.We claim $N(x,\epsilon)\subset A-B$.Let $p\in N(x,\epsilon)$,then $p\in A$.But $p\notin B$ as $N(x,\epsilon)\cap B=\phi$,So $p\in A-B$,thus $N(x,\epsilon)\subset A-B$.So $x \in (A-B)^0$.Thus $A^0-\bar B\subset (A-B)^0$.This completes the proof.

( **I have added the trivial cases too.**)
Suppose $(A-B)^0=\phi$.Let if possible $A^0-\bar B$ be non empty.then there is some $x_0$ in that set.then as per the previous result $x_0 \in (A-B)^0$,which contradicts that $(A-B)^0 =\phi$,thus it is not possible for $A^0-\bar B$ to be non empty,hence $A^0-\bar B=\phi=(A-B)^0$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using well known properties of int and closure and simple set theory:

$$\operatorname{int}(A - B)=\operatorname{int}(A \cap B^\complement)=\operatorname{int}(A) \cap \operatorname{int}(B^\complement) = \operatorname{int}(A) \cap \overline{B}^\complement = \operatorname{int}(A)-\overline{B}$$